# Howto use WP built in Thickbox for images?

Tags: images, javascript, thickbox

I've been searching for a better way to utilize the built in Thickbox function for images. I've been using my method for a few months, but I don't think it's the best way to do it. Here is the code I've been using (I don't remember where I found the code or I'd link to the article):

```
<?php
if (!is_admin()){
/*
add a word found in your domain name
*/
$mydomain = ".com";
/*
The css selector
.entry-content a img 
*/
$myselector = "p a img";
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox'); //include thickbox .css
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  //include jQuery
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox'); //include Thickbox jQuery plugin
    // Function that will write js
    function thickbox_js(){
        global $mydomain, $myselector;
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
         var tb_closeImage = "<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-includes/js/thickbox/tb-close.png";
         var tb_pathToImage = "<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-includes/js/thickbox/loadingAnimation.gif";
         jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             jQuery("<?php echo $myselector; ?>").parent("a[href*=<?php echo $mydomain; ?>]").addClass("thickbox");
         });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
add_action('wp_footer', 'thickbox_js'); // use wp_footer hook to write our generated javascript into page footer.
}
?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've tried several different methods listed in tutorials, but none have worked. Thanks...

**To be more specific, this is the part in question:**

```
<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>
```

**What I'm using now:**

```
<?php
    function add_themescript(){
     if(!is_admin()){
     wp_enqueue_script('thickbox',null,array('jquery'));
     wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
     }
}
 add_action('init','add_themescript');

define("IMAGE_FILETYPE", "(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)", true);
function wp_thickbox($string) {
$pattern = '/(<a(.*?)href="([^"]*.)'.IMAGE_FILETYPE.'"(.*?)><img)/ie';
$replacement = 'stripslashes(strstr("\2\5","rel=") ? "\1" : "<a\2href=\"\3\4\"\5 class=\"thickbox\"><img")';
  return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}

function wp_thickbox_rel( $attachment_link ) {
$attachment_link = str_replace( 'a href' , 'a rel="thickbox-gallery" class="thickbox" href' , $attachment_link );
  return $attachment_link;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wp_thickbox');
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link' , 'wp_thickbox_rel');
?>
```

I thinks that's a little better, but I'm still not sure it's the optimal way. Next I need to learn how to add navigation to the ThickBox pop-up images.

Comment: this looks about right

Comment: Thanks Bainternet, I've revised to question to be more specific. One more question, how would I allow showing all images on a post/page? Let me know if this should this be a separate question and I'll re-post it in more detail. Thanks, Jeremy Jared.

Comment: CSS enqueues should go in the head, JS is fine in the footer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try adding this to your functions.php

```
function tb(){
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox',null,array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','tb');
```

and keeping your bit of jQuery (not sure what your are needing those php variables for):

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
             jQuery("img").parent("a").addClass("thickbox");
         });
```

Comment: Hi Zac ,could you give a complete sample of the code as you would use it? I've tried implementing your suggestion with not luck. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Hi Jeremy,  When you add that function do you see thickbox loaded in your source?

Comment: Enqueues should never be done on init.

Comment: I ended up trying something else. I couldn't get Zac's code to work, but I notice it is very similar to what I am using now. I've been using the beta testers plug-in on most of my development sites. This seems to have caused some issues with my script and the ones that were suggested. It notice things were strange when I checked my permalinks, and they kept switching on me. After investigation things, I realized it was because I was using an unstable version of WordPress. I switched to the latest reslease and everything is working like expected now.

Comment: @t31os I was having an annoying white flash on my site as the DOM was loading improperly.  I remembered your comment and taking it off init was what it needed.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

*The accepted answer above is a bit dated, and since then it's gotten a lot easier to add a Thickbox gallery to default WordPress sites.*

### 1: Enqueue thickbox JS and CSS

This can now be done quite easily using the built-in WordPress default handles:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse25112_scripts' );
function wpse25112_scripts(){
  // enqueue the thickbox scripts and styles
  wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );

  // enqueue your own JavaScript
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-thickbox-script', 'path/to/my-thickbox-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'thickbox' ), '1.0.0' );
}
```

### 2: Activate Thickbox on WordPress Gallery Images

This can be done using a bit of jQuery inside your custom JavaScript file that we enqueued in the above bit of code:

```
;jQuery(function($){
    $(".gallery a").addClass("thickbox");
});
```

This ensures we're only adding Thickbox functionality to the WordPress gallery images (not every `img` wrapped in an `a` tag as per other examples).

### 3: Create your gallery

This is done through the WordPress Add Media button on any Post or Page. Just look for the "Gallery" tab. **Important**: make sure that you choose "link to media file" rather than "link to attachment" in order for the image to properly pop up in the Thickbox modal (otherwise a copy of your web page will pop up instead!).

### 4: Bonus! Make sure you're only enqueueing this stuff when there's actually a WordPress gallery present on the page

This is the fun part. Why enqueue 16K of scripts and CSS (okay, that's really not a lot but still) when you don't need it? Here we check to see whether there's actually the `[gallery]` shortcode somewhere in the content before we actually enqueue anything...

Modify the above enqueue function as follows:

```
function wpse25112_scripts(){
    /** @var WP_Post $post */
    $post = get_post();

    // Short circuit if something goes wrong
    if ( ! is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) ){
        return;
    }

    // Does this Post have the default WordPress [gallery] shortcode?
    if ( preg_match( "/\[\s*gallery(?:\s|\])/i", $post->post_content ) ){
        // enqueue the thickbox scripts and styles
        wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );

        // enqueue your own JavaScript
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-thickbox-script', 'path/to/my-thickbox-script.js', array( 'jquery', 'thickbox' ), '1.0.0' );
    }
}
```